# If one tick label is too long, how to constrain the length and let it show in multi-lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to do some plots by matplotlib, but there is a problem that some of my tick labels are too long. I wonder if I can make long tick labels show in multi-lines.

Here is some code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random(4)
idx = np.arange(4)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 4-0.5)
ax.set_yticks(b)
ax.tick_params(length=0)
ax.barh(idx, data, zorder=2, 
        tick_label=["qwertyuioplkjhgfdsa+1s",
        "abc","asd","qwerty"])
ax.grid(axis='x')

plt.show()
```

So here is the plot I got.
[image: result]

As you can see, the bottom ytick label is too long, and I want to set each line 10 letters at most, so I hope that tick label could be shown in

```
qwertyuiop
lkjhgfdsa+
1s
```

or somewhat not so long in one line.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `textwrap` module of python. E.g. to wrap at 10 characters:

```
import textwrap
f = lambda x: textwrap.fill(x.get_text(), 10)
ax.set_yticklabels(map(f, ax.get_yticklabels()))
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding \n to it

```
ax.barh(idx, data, zorder=2, 
            tick_label=["qwertyuiop \n lkjhgfdsa+ \n 1s",
            "abc","asd","qwerty"])
```

Comment: In fact I get the tick labels from somewhere else, so gmds' solution works for me. But still thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the tick labels right before showing your plot to have a newline every `max_chars` characters:

```
max_chars = 10

new_labels = ['\n'.join(label._text[i:i + max_chars ] 
                        for i in range(0, len(label._text), max_chars ))
              for label in ax.get_yticklabels()]

ax.set_yticklabels(new_labels)
```